# DataBind and DataSource on a Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have done gridviews before, where I bind all SQL data from data safe reader or specify column names and binds at the javascript level. This is a bit different and I am a bit stumped on how to proceed.

I have a business class that handles all SQL data queries.

This class is called to Fetch a LIST. This list contains collections and child collections.

```
var _InfoList = BusinessObjectClass.Get(_CriteriaKey);
```

I can access the list as such:-

```
Txtbox1.Text = _InfoList.ID#.ToString();
```

Now I am trying to bind one of the collections in the LIST to a gridview.:-

```
C#:-

gvwMembers.DataSource = _InfoList.Members;
gvwMembers.DataBind();
```

Where Members is a collection...

But this syntax doesn't add any thing to the gridview...The gridview is empty.

Second methodology:-

I also tried doing something like this:-

```
 List<BusinessObjectClass> Members = new List<BusinessObjectClass>();
 Members = _InfoList.Members;

 gvwVendors.DataSource = Members;
 gvwVendors.DataBind();
```

But to no avail.. this is because the problem lies in the 2nd statement:-

`Members = _InfoList.Members`.... this is not a valid assignment...can anyone help with this?

Comment: What data type is returned from `BusinessObjectClass.Get(_CriteriaKey);`? And what is the datatype of `_InfoList.Members`? I imagine `_InfoList.Members` is not a list of `BusinessObjectClass` but of a type within `BusinessObjectClass`.

Comment: Well my business class has a bunch of objects... based on a criteria, it fetches information from the SQL server and returns them to the _InfoList... strings,ints,Collections and child collections.

_InfoList.Members is a collection... it will have its own Names, IDs, DOB, etc... and yes you are right about the last part... I just need to find a way I can assign it back to gridview... I can see that the results are returned correctly.

Comment: Ok, so what is `_InfoList.Members` a collection of? Is it a list of Employee objects or something like that? We may also need to see the code of your GridView to see if you are binding properly since you say the GridView is empty.

Comment: Its a list of students. The gridview is simple man..nothing in it.
<asp:GridView ID="gvwVendors" runat="server"> </asp:GridView>>

Comment: Well if you say the results return correctly and your GridView is just that, then everything should work. Make sure `AutoGenerateColumns` isn't false and it should create the necessary columns for a `Student`. Otherwise all I can really say is verify the data is good.

Comment: ahh snap....autogeneratecolumns!!!

Comment: one more question:- What if I dont want all the columns to be autogenerated from the collection..should i specify under the gridview which columns i want and specify their data bound field name?

Comment: Yep, exactly. There are a couple ways to do it and that is one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fleshing out some details in the comments, it is perfectly fine to have a simple GridView with no columns defined, but make sure `AutoGenerateColumns` is not false. The default is true. This will create a column for you, based on each property of the object being bound.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true">
</asp:GridView>
```

And in order to pick and choose which properties to display, define them in the `<Columns>` section.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Property1" HeaderText="Property1" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Property2">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblProperty2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Property2") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: which other way is there to pick and choose which column to bind to the gridview?

Comment: I just mean how you can choose to have an `<asp:BoundField />` or an `<asp:TemplateField />`, etc... I have shown BoundField and TemplateField in my answer above. A BoundField will display the text as is whereas a TemplateField provides you the ability to define a control to bind the data to.